# Show input from the second select option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having trouble showing input after the user selects an option from the second select menu option. Also whenever the user selects any of the second select options it has should show their input.

Sorry about the confusing title, but basically my question is how do I use the selection from one dropdown menu to decide which dropdown menu shows up next? I want to do something like this:

- Select menu

  - option #1
  - option #2
  - option #3

Selecting option #2 would open another select menu:

- sub-option #1.1
- sub-option #1.2
- sub-option #1.3

and then when the user select option from would open another select option 2 it will show  label of what is select and input box so the user can input text

```js
$("[data-child]").change(function() {
  const selectedGroup = $(this).val();
  var $childSelect = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-child"));
  value = $childSelect.find('option').hide()
    .filter(function(i, e) {
      return $(e).val().startsWith(selectedGroup)
    }).show().eq(0).val();
  $childSelect.val(value);
  $childSelect.trigger('change');
});

$("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger('change');
//codes for input
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#niv1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "1-1-2") {
      $("#other").removeAttr("disabled")
    } else {
      $("#other").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmContact" id="" frmContact "" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>ID Service Request Form</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Please fill out with the information that is requested below and submit the id request form. Thank you!</p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Request Type</legend>
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Select a option:</td>
        <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
          <select name="category1" id="category1">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            <option value="a">AS400</option>
            <option value="w">Windows</option>
            <option value="o">Outlook</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">Select a option:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
          <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category2" name="category2">
            <option value>Select Category</option>
            <!-- AS400 -->
            <optgroup data-rel="a">
              <option value="1">Modify Account</option>
              <option value="2">New AS400 Account</option>
              <option value="3">Change Deapartment</option>
              <option value="3">Reset Password</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- windows -->
            <optgroup data-rel="w">
              <option value="1">Create Domain ID</option>
              <option value="2">Access to Particular Folder/Drive</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- Outlook -->
            <optgroup data-rel="o">
              <option value="1">Plish Mail</option>
              <option value="2">Notification</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you want to show specific options conditionally based on the Users selection. Do you see any Console errors when you run your current code?

Comment: no it doesnt but when i tryied to add a input box but check to see if it works but after the user select the second option it does do anyything

Comment: If you edit your snippet above, then on the left under Options, there is a dropdown that says `No jQuery`. Click that and change it to `jQuery 3.3.1`.

Comment: @JavaWorld I don't see any code to handle the second dropdown tho. You only handle the `change` of the category1 dropdown.

Comment: i try very few methods but i didnt wrote it here since it wont work, so i needed help to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#category1").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == "") {
      $("#category2").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#category2 optgroup").hide();
      $("#category2 > option").not(":first").remove();
      var options = $("#category2 optgroup[data-rel='" + selected + "']").children().clone().appendTo("#category2");
      $("#category2").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmContact" id="" frmContact "" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>ID Service Request Form</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Please fill out with the information that is requested below and submit the id request form. Thank you!</p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Request Type</legend>
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Select a option:</td>
        <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
          <select name="category1" id="category1">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            <option value="a">AS400</option>
            <option value="w">Windows</option>
            <option value="o">Outlook</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">Select a option:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
          <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category2" name="category2">
            <option value>Select Category</option>
            <!-- AS400 -->
            <optgroup data-rel="a">
              <option value="1">Modify Account</option>
              <option value="2">New AS400 Account</option>
              <option value="3">Change Deapartment</option>
              <option value="3">Reset Password</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- windows -->
            <optgroup data-rel="w">
              <option value="1">Create Domain ID</option>
              <option value="2">Access to Particular Folder/Drive</option>
            </optgroup>
            <!-- Outlook -->
            <optgroup data-rel="o">
              <option value="1">Plish Mail</option>
              <option value="2">Notification</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

This shows and hides selected categories in `#category2` when `#category1` is changed.

Comment: thats shortens the code which is solves some of the problem. My problem is for example when the user selects AS400 from 1st select and then Department change from the second select it should show a label with the input text and if they the user goest back to first option and select another option it should  hid the other option and select what he choose or selects

Comment: @JavaWorld where is the Input element? I do not see this in your example. You did not specify this in your post. Please ensure you have a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it should have all elements and tested code.

Comment: ill add now what i tried and i will update the snippet in some of the help i got from co worker

Comment: @JavaWorld I see the updates. I now see references to elements that do not exist in your HTML. Can you update all of it to include all parts that are needed.